# Calculating data from a file as input

Tags: c

> **It was resolved.**

**I made a terrible mistake. I did not initialize the global variable.**

**Thank you for all your help.**

I want to read a line by line, then turn it into a postfix expression and finally calculate it.
So I wrote the code below.

1. Enter an expression ending with $ in the text file.
2. and read the string as a function of ' fgets '.
3. Separate strings with ' $ ', and clear the newline and pass it to the convPost parameter.
4. Outputs results for testing.

It doesn't matter as long as I printed the input string and changed it to postfix expression.

```
char * convPost(char * charArray)
{
    stack_C * temp = malloc(sizeof(stack_C));
    (*temp).arr = malloc(SIZE * sizeof(char));
    (*temp).top = -1;
    char * postFix = malloc(SIZE * sizeof(char));
    for(int i = 0; i < charArray[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if((isdigit(charArray[i])||(isalpha(charArray[i]))))
        {
            do
                postFix[arrIndex++] = charArray[i++];
            while(isdigit(charArray[i])||(isalpha(charArray[i])));
            postFix[arrIndex++] = ' ';
            i--;
        }
        else if(charArray[i] == ')')
        {
            while((*temp).arr[(*temp).top] != '(')
                postFix[arrIndex++] = pop(temp);
            pop(temp);
        }
        else if(checkPrec(temp, charArray[i], (*temp).top))
        {
            while(checkPrec(temp, charArray[i], (*temp).top))
                postFix[arrIndex++] = pop(temp);
            push(temp, charArray[i]);
        }
        else
            push(temp, charArray[i]);

    }
    for(int i = (*temp).top; i >= 0; i--)
        postFix[arrIndex++] = pop(temp);

    printPostFix(postFix, arrIndex);
    return postFix;
}

int evalPostExpr(char * postFix)
{
    int i, op1, op2;
    stack_C * eval = malloc(sizeof(stack_C));
    eval->arr = malloc(SIZE*sizeof(int));
    eval->top = -1;
    for(i = 0; postFix[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if(isdigit(postFix[i]))
            push(eval,convInt(&postFix[i], &i));
        else if(postFix[i] == ' ')
            i++;
        else
        {
            op2 = pop(eval);
            op1 = pop(eval);
            switch(isOper(&postFix[i]))
            {
                case plus: push(eval, op1 + op2); break;
                case minus: push(eval, op1 - op2); break;
                case multiply: push(eval, op1 * op2); break;
                case divide: push(eval, op1 / op2); break;
                case modulus: push(eval, op1 % op2); break;
            }
        }
    }
    return pop(eval);
}

// main 함수
int main(void)
{
    FILE* data;
    char expr[SIZE];
    char * result;
    char str[] = "$";
    char * test;
    if((data = fopen("data.txt", "rt") )== NULL)
    {
        puts("failed to open");
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        while(fgets(expr,SIZE, data) != NULL)
        {
        expr[strlen(expr)-1] = '\0';
        printf("The string is %s\n", expr);
        result = strtok(expr, str);
        test = convPost(expr);

        printf("%s\n", test);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but here's that result.

```
The string is 6*(3+2)-9*(3-2)$
6 3 2 +*9 3 2 -*-
6 3 2 +*9 3 2 -*-
The string is 8+3*5/(4-2)%6+9$
8 3 5 *4 2 -/6 %+9 +
```

It works well for the first string, but a space is output for the second.

I have no idea why that result is coming.
I've been looking for a solution for days. I've tried many ways, but I can't come up with an answer.
What did I do wrong? why????

Comment: I don't understand the loop condition `i < charArray[i] != '\0';`

Comment: "I've been looking for a solution for days." Does this include stepping through your code in a debugger? (It should). Please [edit] the question to indicate what such debugging has told you.

Comment: I am not good at communicating English. Please excuse me.
It is to remove '\n'.

Comment: The loop condition `i < charArray[i] != '\0'` is certainly wrong. Because the `<` and `!=` operators have the same precedence and they are evaluated from left-to-right, what happens is you are checking the current character in the string against the counter `i`,  this evaluates to `0` or `1` and then this result is checked if it's '0` or `1`. The final result is - if the current character in the array has value bigger than the counter '1', the condition is true, otherwise it's false.